# how to deploy single app for multiple app name in play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Can we have multiple app with same apk file? We have developed POS application which support multiple stores. Each store will have their own icon and/or app name. However all these stores will be handled by our single apk file. So in this case in play store there will be multiple icons or multiple app names but only one apk file.

Please let us know how can we do this.

Comment: nobody can have answer of above question.

Comment: you can only have one package name, so answer is no it's not possible. What you can do is update store names in play store description text ( follow the standards mentioned by google, don't add simple hashtags ). Once keywords are picked up by google, when user searches for store 2, app will be displayed. but only single app. as of now no dynamic listing of app possible in google play store

Comment: is it possible in apple store ?if you know then

Comment: not possible in iTunes